# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err; when running express.js

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I was trying to make an express app following a tutorial.

But it gave an error of  Cannot find module

> PS C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend> cd .\express
> PS C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express> ls

> Directory: C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express

> Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
>
> ---
>
> -a----        30-11-2022     04:33            279 app.js

> PS C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express> node app.js
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> throw err;
> ^

> Error: Cannot find module 'express'
> Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express\app.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>   at Object. (C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express\app.js:1:16)
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: [ 'C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express\app.js' ]
>   }
>   PS C:\Users\abhis\Desktop\backend\express>

````
app.js

```

```
const express= require ("express");
const app= express();
const port= 80;


app.get("/", (req, res)=> {  
  res.send("This is my first express app")
});

app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log(`The application started succesfully ${port}`)
});
```

```



  package.json

     ```

     ```
 {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "github"
  },
  "author": "abhishek kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

```
````

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run `npm install` and then `npm start` to run the project after updating `package.json` file

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
...
```